# Running an animated loop in PIXI.JS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to create a bottle pouring animation that loops through 5 different bottles, each bottle is sideways and has a different amount of liquid pouring out. I am trying to display the first bottle and then the second after 60ms, then the 3rd after 60ms, and so on and so on. I need to remove the previous bottle and add the next bottle in the exact same place. I am wondering what the most concise way to do with would be, I have tried with several setTimout functions but the code has some bugs and is not concise at all. I have researched PIXI.Timer but am struggling to understand how to set 5 different sprites and loop through them. Let me know if you have any ideas or direction. I will post my function with setTimout used below:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        let pour1Texture = new PIXI.Texture.from(require('@/assets/items/bottle/pouring/pouring bottle1.png'))
        let pour1 = new PIXI.Sprite.from(pour1Texture)
        sprites.push(pour1)
        pour1.position.x = 438;
        pour1.position.y = -40;
        labBenchComponent.pixiApp.stage.addChild(
            pour1
          );
    },1000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        labBenchComponent.pixiApp.stage.removeChild(sprites.pop())
        const pour2Texture = new PIXI.Texture.from(require('@/assets/items/bottle/pouring/pouring bottle2.png'))
        const pour2 = new PIXI.Sprite.from(pour2Texture)
        pour2.position.x = 438;
        pour2.position.y = -10;
        sprites.push(pour2)
        labBenchComponent.pixiApp.stage.addChild(
            pour2
          );
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        labBenchComponent.pixiApp.stage.removeChild(sprites.pop())
        const pour3Texture = new PIXI.Texture.from(require('@/assets/items/bottle/pouring/pouring bottle2.png'))
        const pour3 = new PIXI.Sprite.from(pour3Texture)
        pour3.position.x = 438;
        pour3.position.y = 10;
        sprites.push(pour3)
        labBenchComponent.pixiApp.stage.addChild(
            pour3
          );
    }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of using a tick use PIXI.AnimatedSprite like the following:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js-legacy';

export default function pourBottle() {
    let textureArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        let texture = {
            texture: PIXI.Texture.from(require(`@/assets/items/bottle/pouring/pouring bottle${i+1}.png`)),
            time: 100,
        };
        textureArray.push(texture);
    };

    let animatedSprite = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(textureArray);
    return animatedSprite;
}
```